# How to calculate the datetime by TLE and a coodinate?

Tags: python, geopy, pyorbital

I have a Sat's TLE data and a point in (lat, lon), how can I calculate the datetime when that Sat pass the point? I tried as below, but I got `The CSS will reachreach (40.9666, 100.3) from current position: -17640 days, 3:37:58.629410`, is this formular right?

```
from pyorbital.orbital import Orbital
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from geopy.distance import geodesic

# Read the TLE data
line1 = '1 48274U 21035A   23130.95833333  .00039478  00000-0  41428-3 0  9995'
line2 = '2 48274  41.4746  22.2773 0007252 240.9783   2.2489 15.63002554116021'
name = "CSS"

# Parse the TLE data
orb = Orbital(name, line1=line1, line2=line2)

# The point
coord = (40.9666, 100.3)  

# Calculate the position and velocity of the satellite at a specific time
time = datetime.utcnow()
pos, vel = orb.get_position(time)

# Calculate the distance between the sat's current position and the point
dist = geodesic((pos[0], pos[1]), coord).km

# Calculate the time it would take for the satellite to reach the point
time_to_reach = timedelta(hours=dist / vel[0])

print(f"The {name} will reachreach ({coord[0]}, {coord[1]}) from current position: {time_to_reach}")
```